# Moving UIView OFF the screen from left to right and bring it IN again from left

Tags: ios, animation, uiview

How can I Move an UIView OFF the screen from left to right and then bring it IN the screen again from left side ?!!

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Are you able to do either of those things in isolation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All you have to do is animate the x origin position of the view and use the devices screen with to determine how much. So for off screen to the right:

```
CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
CGFloat screenWidth = screenRect.size.width;

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut animations:^{
    _yourView.frame = CGRectMake(screenRect.size.width, _yourView.frame.origin.y, _yourView.frame.size.width, _yourView.frame.size.height);
}
                 completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                     //position screen left after animation
                     _yourView.frame = CGRectMake(-screenRect.size.width, _yourView.frame.origin.y, _yourView.frame.size.width, _yourView.frame.size.height);
                 }];
```

And for on screen go back to 0.0 x-position or whatever your starting point was:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut animations:^{
    _yourView.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, _yourView.frame.origin.y, _yourView.frame.size.width, _yourView.frame.size.height);
}
                 completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                     //do something after animation
                 }];
```

Answer (score 3):

To move OFF the screen:

```
CGRect frame = viewToMove.frame;
frame.origin.x = self.view.frame.size.width;
viewToMove.frame = frame;
```

To move the view back into the screen:

```
CGRect frame = viewToMove.frame;
frame.origin.x = 0;
viewToMove.frame = frame;
```

Comment: That would move it off the screen to the right side.  Depending where they want it to move off the screen, they would adjust x or y accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

```
//Store your view's original rect
UIRect originRect = yourView.frame;

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^{

//create new rect and set its X coord to phone's width
CGrect rect = originRect;
rect.origin.x = self.view.frame.size.width;
yourView.frame = rect;

} completion:^(BOOL finished){

   // when animation finished animating start new animation 
   //to bring your view to its original position

   [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animation:^{

   yourView.frame = originRect;

   }];

}];
```

Comment: With a bit of cleanup, this was the easiest for me.

Answer (score 1):

This code will move it to right in 0.3 seconds and then back from left to it's current position again in the next 0.3 seconds.

```
CGRect backToOriginal = Yourview.frame;
CGRect frameOnRight = CGRectMake ( screenWidth,backToOriginal.origin.y,backToOriginal.frame.size.width,backToOriginal.frame.size.height);

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn animations:^{ Yourview.frame = frameOnRight; } completion:^(BOOL finished)[UIView setFrame: screenLeft;] [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn animations:^{ Yourview.frame = backToOriginal; }{ }];
```

There must be errors in this code in terms of syntax since I am not sitting on a MAC right now.

Answer (score 1):

//To move view to left

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                      delay:1.0
                    options: UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut
                 animations:^{
                     self.yourView.frame = CGRectMake(distanceToLeft, distanceFromTop, yourView.width, yourView.height);
                     }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){
                     NSLog(@"Moved to left!");
                 }];
```

//  To move back to original position

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                      delay:1.0
                    options: UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut
                 animations:^{
                     self.yourView.frame = CGRectMake(originalX, OriginalY, yourView.Width, yourView.height);
                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){
                     NSLog(@"Back to normal!");
                 }];
```